# How to make visible light sensor module

Tags: led, light, circuit, baud-rate, npn

How to make [visible light sensor](https://www.sunrom.com/p/light-sensor-module-photodiode) module from existing [LDR module](https://www.sunrom.com/p/light-sensing-module-ldr) (I have one of it). Both of it have same circuit but different sensors. So,I would like to buy phototransistor separately as LDR is slow to respond to ***5mm while LED which flickers at >56000 baud rate***.

[Circuit Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM1eL.jpg)

Can I replace sensor in circuit diagram with [TEPT5600](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84768/tept5600.pdf) phototransistor [official page](http://www.vishay.com/photo-detectors/list/product-84768).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You might have better luck at: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can replace the LDR sensor with a phototransistor like TEPT5600/TEPT4400 which works at ~20ns(which is suitable for >9600 BR). The Collector needs to go to pin 2 (+) and the Emitter to pin 1 (-).